# Leer archivo de texto y ordenar texto en datagridview vb.net win-forms

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

estoy trabajando con un archivo de texto que luce así:

```
----------------------------------------
Récord por alumno
Version:  4
`Tue Feb 06 14:09:12 2018`
----------------------------------------
5%Carrera 100 mts
Subprueba: 50 mts
Measured:   15.2
High Limit: 12.00
Low Limit:  18.00
Time in Seconds
Status:  2nd place
----------------------------------------
4%Lagartijas 20 en 25 seg
Subprueba: 10 en 10 seg
Measured:   24
High Limit: 25
Time in Seconds
Status:  2nd place
----------------------------------------
Alumno : Cervantes,Gonzalo
----------------------------------------
5%Carrera 100 mts
Subprueba: 50 mts
Measured:   14.7
High Limit: 12.00
Low Limit:  18.00
Time in Seconds
Status:  1nd place
----------------------------------------
4%Lagartijas 20 en 25 seg
Subprueba: 10 en 10 seg
Measured:   25
High Limit: 25
Time in Seconds
Status:  1nd place
----------------------------------------
Alumno : Hernandez,Pedro
----------------------------------------
5%Carrera 100 mts
Subprueba: 50 mts
Measured:   15.2
High Limit: 12.00
Low Limit:  18.00
Time in Seconds
Status:  2nd place
----------------------------------------
3%Lagartijas 22 en 25 seg
Subprueba: 10 en 10 seg
Measured:   24
High Limit: 25
Time in Seconds
Status:  2nd place
----------------------------------------
Alumno : Ramirez,José
```

y este es el código que estoy trabajando:

```
     Private Sub Btn_ejecutar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_ejecutar.Click

    Dim fName As String = ""
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\Test\"
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files(*.Txt)|*.txt"
    OpenFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    OpenFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
    If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        fName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    End If
    TextBox1.Text = fName
    Dim TextLine As String = ""

    If System.IO.File.Exists(fName) = True Then
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(TextBox1.Text, Encoding.ASCII)
        Dim index As Integer = 0
        Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
            If index > 0 Then
                TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()

                Dim arr() As String = {TextLine}

                Dim value1 As String = Array.Find(arr, Function(x) (x.Contains("2018")))
                Dim value2 As String = Array.Find(arr, Function(x) (x.Contains("%")))
                Dim value3 As String = Array.Find(arr, Function(x) (x.StartsWith("Measured:")))
                Dim value4 As String = Array.Find(arr, Function(x) (x.StartsWith("High Limit:")))
                Dim value5 As String = Array.Find(arr, Function(x) (x.StartsWith("Low Limit:")))
                Dim value6 As String = Array.Find(arr, Function(x) (x.StartsWith("Alumno : ")))

                If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(value1) Or Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(value2) Or Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(value3) Or Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(value4) Or Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(value5) Or Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(value6)) Then

                    Dim allarray() As String = {value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6}
                    dt.LoadDataRow(allarray, True)
                End If

            Else
                TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
            End If
            index = index + 1
        Loop

        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

    Else
        MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
    End If

End Sub
```

Sin embargo al generar los array obtengo espacios en blanco haciendo que la información aparezca escalonada, no he sido capaz de ordenarla en un sólo renglón y ya me estoy quedando pelón de darle tantas vueltas al asunto, anexo imagen de mi resultado contra lo que esperaría leer, agradezco mucho la guía que me puedan dar para resolver este problema. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es normal, ya que en cada iteración solo obtienes un dato, con lo que rellenas el datatable solo con el dato encontrado. Los datos van siempre en el mismo orden en el archivo?

Comment: Sí, el archivo es generado por un programita así que nunca varía, siempre es el mismo patrón.

Comment: De todas maneras, ese formato es horrible y complicadisimo de parsear. Si puedes modificar el programa que genera esto, hazlo. Usa json o algun otro formato de datos estructurado